# Can I file test/ null provisional/ non provisional patent?

Tags: filing, pro-se

I will try to file a test patent, basically a null patent for familiarizing with the filing process without spending any money. Is there any legal issue with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Manual for Patent Examination (MPEP) has some sections that mention that anything submitted "is not being presented for any improper purpose, such as to harass, cause unnecessary delay, . . ".  A famous not really an application is "Method and instrument for proposing marriage to an individual" [US 20070078663 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20070078663) .  I wouldn't file anything that seemed to be signed.